# Arbitrarily nesting some attributes in rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, rabl

I'm designing a new API for my project, and I want to return objects that have nested children as json. For that purpose i've decided to use RABL.

I want the client side to be able to understand whether the object is valid, and if not which fields are missing in order to save it correctly.

The design I thought of should include some fields as optional, under an optional hash, and the rest are required. The required fields should appear right under the root of the json.
So the output I try to describe should look something like this:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "optional": {
        "address": "Beverly Hills 90210",
        "phones":[{"number":"123456","name":"work"}, {"number":"654321","name":"mobile"}]
    }
}
```

The above output example describes the required fields name and last name, and the not required address and phones (which is associated in a belongs_to-has_many relationship to the object). name, last_name and address are User's DB fields.

Playing with RABL I didn't manage so far to create this kind of structure.

Any suggestions? I'm looking for a DRY way to implement this for all my models.

Answer (score 1):

RABL is really good in creating JSON structures on the fly, so I don't see why you couldn't achieve your goal. Did you try testing if a field is set to null-able in the schema, and thus presenting it as optional? It seems a good approach for me. For the nested children, just do the same, but extend the template for the children.

For example, in your `father/show.rabl` display a custom node `:optional` with all the properties that can be null.

Then, create a `child/show.rabl` with the same logic. Finally, go back to `father/show.rabl` and add a child node, extending the `child/show.rabl` template. This way you could achieve unlimited levels of "optionals".

Hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd use the free form option.

From https://github.com/nesquena/rabl

> There can also be odd cases where the root-level of the response
>   doesn't map directly to any object.
>
> In those cases, object can be assigned to 'false'
>   and nodes can be constructed free-form.

```
object false
node(:some_count) { |m| @user.posts.count }
child(@user) { attribute :name }
```